# Killing a dialog box that doesn't show up in the dock

Tags: macos, dock, performance, activity-monitor

There's lots of information out there about how to kill an application that's not responding. But what if I just have some dialog box that isn't clearly associated with any running application? In particular, there's nothing in the dock that corresponds to the dialog box in question, and even when I attempt to shift focus to the dialog box, the menu bar at the top of the screen remains the menu bar of whatever application was running before.

Here's the dialog box that was freezing on me:
[image: Dialog box that freezes]

I tried using Activity Monitor but there wasn't anything obvious to kill.

Comment: That's nasty behavior - looks like Microsoft's Remote Desktop icon - have you run that or installed it recently?

Comment: @bmike, yes, this is from Microsoft's Remote Desktop application. I have used it from this machine many times in the past, but the option to save the certificate was new, so presumably I'm running a recently updated version. And it seems that the new feature did not agree with my system for some reason.